# Json path get all first attributes

Tags: java, jsonpath, jsonparser

I have below json, I am trying to fetch 1st attributes from each nodes, using jsonPath.

```
 {   "data": {
        "unpredictable_name_1": {
          "inner_data": [
            {
              "wanted_data": "something1",
              "other_data": 1000
            },
            {
              "wanted_data": "something2",
              "other_data": 1001
            }
          ],
          "something_else_1": "some_data"
        },
        "unpredictable_name_2": {
          "inner_data": [
            {
              "wanted_data": "something1",
              "other_data": 1000
            },
            {
              "wanted_data": "something2",
              "other_data": 1001
            }
          ]
        }   } }
```

I want to extract below :

```
{
    unpredictable_name_1, 
    unpredictable_name_2
}
```

I am using jway-json path. Please help me with the jsonPath expression.

Comment: In not sure about the specific library, but JSON Path didn't support getting keys, only values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code helped me get all the json attributes only -

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
      JsonElement element = parser.parse(jsonStr);
      JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject();
      Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = obj.entrySet();
      for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry: entries) {
         System.out.println(entry.getKey());
      }
```

Thanks to [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-all-the-keys-of-a-json-object-using-gson-in-java)